# Vuetify Input Mask

Tags: vuetify.js, masking

Has anyone found an Input Mask library that works with Vuetify using a directive? I have tried Cleave.js, vue-mask, imask, and a few other and they all seem to fall short or are buggy. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

is there a specific thing that you are trying to achieve, the mask that they have by default you can use to mask text fields already they have some pre-made and you can customize to your needs. I'm just curious as what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response. I have looked at the provided masks but they dont work for my needs. For instance, I want to have an input field that only accepts numbers but isnt limited to the amount of numbers. If I put mask="####" as the attribute it will only allow numbers but only 4 digits. If I want to allow unlimited numbers how would I accomplish that? Thanks for your help

Comment: This directive is no longer supported since vue 2.0.0